# add confirmation for deleting using UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c

When you long press on an item in my app a UIMenuController pops up and gives me a few options. One of which is to delete.

Here is an example of what that looks like:

```
- (void)messageCellDidLongPress:(FCIMessageCell *)cell
{
self.cellShowingMenuController = cell;
[self becomeFirstResponder];
self.messageMenuController               = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
self.messageMenuController.anchorView    = cell.bodyLabel;
self.messageMenuController.presentInView = cell;
[self.messageMenuController updatePosition];
UIMenuItem *editMenuItem   = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" action:@selector(edit:)];
UIMenuItem *unsendMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unsend" action:@selector(unsend:)];
UIMenuItem *infoMenuItem   = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Details" action:@selector(info:)];
self.messageMenuController.menuItems = @[unsendMenuItem, editMenuItem, infoMenuItem];
[self.messageMenuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
//Delete button doesn't appear because its set up to appear on conditions
}
```

What I want to do: Once someone presses the delete button have a "CONFIRM" or "CANCEL" option appear, probably using a UIActionSheet. I'm not too sure how to do that. Where would I put the code to get it to appear. I'm not sure if I need to create an entire other view, or what?

Comment: What's the question? How to create a UIActionSheet in you -edit: method?

Comment: Sorry I edited it to be a tad more clear, but I honestly don't know how to go about doing that. I know what I want, but I don't know how I would get it set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

In .m

```
-(IBAction) edit:(id)sender
{
    self.editSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
        destructiveButtonTitle:@"delete"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [self.editSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
}
```

and later on, in .m

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
    clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (self.editSheet == actionSheet) {

    if((actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) == buttonIndex) {
            // Cancel, do nothing
    } // etc.
}
```

There is a bit more to it, like not creating a sheet if it already exists, possibly handling iPhone & iPad differently, etc.